# Project Compilation Error - cannot find -lwxmsw28

Tags: c++, compilation, wxwidgets

While compiling a project i get the following error as

```
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.6.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find lwxmsw28
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/MinGW-Windows/libRegistration.dll] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

I am using wxwidgets libraries however when i ran a command in cmd as

```
wx-config --libs
```

i could not see lwxmsw28 either let me know if it is downloadable from somewhere or any workaround to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a linker error, rather than a compilation error.

"lwxmsw28" looks to me like a wxwidgets v2.8 microsoft windows library.  Should the linker be looking for this?  Since you are using mingw, I would think you should NOT be linking to msw libraries.  However, I am not familiar with mingw, so maybe this is the name used for mingw libraries.

If this is the correct library, then the next question is: have you built the wxWidgets libraries?  The libraries are NOT "downloadable from somewhere" - you must download the source and build the libraries yourself.

A simple test to find out if you have built the libraries - try to build one of the sample projects.